# Issue on Oracle creating triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

There are two triggers referencing a table.
Both are being triggered after delete or insert or delete on the table.

Which one will run first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one is `before` and second is `after` order is obvious. Also `before statement` goes earlier than `before each row`. If you have two `after insert`  [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i13362) says:

> Although triggers of different types are fired in a specific order, triggers of the same type for the same statement are not guaranteed to fire in any specific order.

Please also see comment bellow that post by @a_horse_with_no_name Since Oracle 11g you can use `follows` and `precedes` to control it.

Comment: You can influence the order in which they fire using the `follows` or `precedes` option when creating or altering a trigger: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS2103

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's interesting. I've removed part of my answer that says it is impossible. Thanks.